# Ball movement needed on click

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a simple flappy bird-esque game in JavaScript in which the goal is for the user to click a button in order to move a ball through a gap between two rectangles. I am having difficulty figuring out how I could both have the ball only move on click rather than being called when the page is loaded, as well as a way to make it so each time the "Go" button is clicked, the ball begins its path/trajectory from the position where it was last at the time of the click. Also i realize and that there is a trail left behind the ball that can be negated however i would like for it to remain if possible. I will consider collisions later but would like some insight with this issue as I am completely new to coding.
Many thanks!

HTML

`<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>`

```
<button id="playGame">Go!</button>
```

CSS

```
canvas { background: #eee;}
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


    function drawBall() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 8, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#68f442";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();  
}

function drawSquare1(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.strokeRect((canvas.width)/2, 0, 20, 200);
   ctx.closePath();
}

function drawSquare2(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
 ctx.strokeRect((canvas.width)/2, 280, 20, 200);
   ctx.closePath();
}

var x = canvas.width/640;
var y = canvas.height+0;
var velocityx = 1;
var velocityy = -2;
var gravity= 0.03;

function draw(){
   drawSquare1();
   drawSquare2();
   drawBall();

    velocityy += gravity; 

    x += velocityx;
    y += velocityy;
}

setInterval(draw, 1);
```

[Here is an image of what i would like to achieve with the clicks, the picture isn't true to the actually arch of the ball in the code, but this is the general idea i am trying to achieve if one was to click at  multiple instances at any point in time. Of course this would look different depending on when the clicks were being made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJfxq.jpg)

Comment: All you need to do is attach a [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) on the canvas.

Comment: Im having some trouble figuring where i would start would it be something along these lines?
canvas.getElementById("playGame").addEventListener("click",OnClick, function drawBall() {

Comment: Your close, I added how you could do that in an answer below. Could you clarify what you are looking for in the "Go" button functionality? Does it *"go back in time"* by one click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment your close, all you need is a simple function for jumping:

```
var jumpPower = 1.5;
/* ... */
function jump(){
    velocityy = -jumpPower;
}
```

Then you can attach a `click` event handler on the canvas so when you click it that `jump` function is triggered:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", jump);
```

Or you could do this all in one step with an anonymous function:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", function(){
    velocityy = -jumpPower;
});
```

[***Here is a fiddle example***](https://jsfiddle.net/tfaqe4go/1/)

Comment: Thanks for you response, I was looking that the fiddle but i think I didnt phrse by question the best. I would like for the "go" button to start the game by initiating the function drawBall. however i also would like that with each subsequent "click" the function is drawn again but starting at the time point of the click  where the first ball is. Could this be achieved all with clicks of the same button or would two be better? I have added a rough sketch of what i would like in the original post

Comment: @codeneophyte The fiddle I implemented is already exactly what you drew in your sketch. When you run the fiddle quickly move your mouse to the canvas and click it, that will make the ball jump. If *"Go"* just restarts the game you can either make it call a reload on the page or have a `init` function which resets things to the default values: [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tfaqe4go/1/).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I had missed what you had implemented earlier! The added code is just what i needed. I do have a question about putting the code in an editor (in my case sublime). I notice that when opening the file locally in Chrome or any other browser, I receive an error message on line 59 
       `document.getElementById("playGame").addEventListener("click", 
        init);` saying that the addEventListener property cannot be read.                     Why is this the case?

Comment: @codeneophyte How is the HTML file structured? JSFiddle atomically runs that JavaScript code on `window.onload`, but it should work as long as the JS is after the elements referenced in the DOM. One thing to try is just past the entire HTML file in the "HTML" section of the fiddle and see if it has the same error.

Comment: Yes it works properly, It was a rookie mistake. I just had the <button> referenced below my external JS file.

Comment: @codeneophyte Great, if this solved your problem I would appreciate if you mark it as the accepted answer.